# Why does Linux not show you an asterisk when you enter a character for a password?

Tags: operating-system, linux

I have enjoyed Linux for about two years now, but I laugh at how hard I failed when I first started my Linux journey. I would try and enter a password and then nothing would happen. I first thought that my keyboard had failed and then I realised, yeah it does not show a star when you enter a password.

Why does Linux operate like this? It seems to be a rather curious way in which Windows and Linux is different.

Comment: Because it tells an observer how long your password is?

Comment: In 1995 it was not yet a problem, all systems worked so. At the time I did not find that surprising. Later, about in 1998, on the first web passwords start to show stars. I have seen them as guidance for people with disabilities. My opinion did not change since then.

Comment: It is simply one of the ways that Linux is superior to Windows.

Comment: Linux does not have a concept of "password". Your question is unclear. Are you talking about a login program? Which one? Which version? How did you configure it? The login program I am using *does* show asterisks (well, circles, actually) in its default configuration, but that is configurable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does Linux operate like this? It seems to be a rather curious way in which Windows and Linux is different.

As Faden already [commented](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17413/why-does-linux-not-show-you-an-asterix-when-you-enter-a-character-for-a-password#comment59248_17413):

**"Because it tells an observer how long your password is"**

And to make at least the answer RetroComputing related, classic mainframe (block) terminals for example had an *invisible* or *dark* field type for secure information. They could be handled/edited (if editable) like other field, except nothing was shown, except for the cursor.

While block mode terminals edit local, thus have no issues of slow lines (during typing), and feedback is given local, character mode devices can't provide this. So there either

- the user gets no feedback - the way (many) unixoides work, or
- some default character is returned per keystroke.

  - On CRT based terminals, which do provide a cursor, a space can be returned, giving about the same feedback as mainframe terminals.
  - On 'cursorless' terminals - like real TTY - a different character had to be used. Some used an asterisk, others used other characters, or even combinations with overstrike.

Now, returning on char per char entered might enable guessing the password length (*1). Thus some OS / hidden field provider returned at random one or more replacement characters, resulting in an arbitrary number of symbols is outputted each time, making length detection a guess (*2).

Windows effectively works somewhat like text mode without cursor mixed with blockmode. While it provides a cursor, it (mostly) uses proportional fonts, so spaces are quite small and would not rally provide a visual feedback. Using an asterisk as feedback is the next best solution.

On the other hand the whole 'hiding' is made only at the output side of an otherwise standard control (*3,*4), so it works more like a block terminal, only allowing a 1:1 relation between invisible character and replacement character.

And finally, selecting an asterisk is for one restrained by the need to use a basic (7-bit) ASCII character, to make it work with essentially all fonts the computer in question may have installed and set as default. Of the characters available the asterisk seams like a good choice simply due being a rather bulky and symmetric character - in some way looking like an overstrike of the original symbol. Other OS have used different characters, like `x` / `X` or similar. In the end it's to each gusto.

---

*1 - When done strictly like some OS did, edit keys are interpreted but also returned as replacement char. So as soon as someone edits the hidden text, the number of symbols does no longer corespondent to the password length, but more often than not people do not edit.

*2 - It's still not really hiding the password length, as the number of symbols does set an upper limit.

*3 - Ofc, all of this could be (and sometimes is) changed with custom controls.

*4 - It's simply the way windows drawing is structured.

Comment: Maybe there is a followup question as to why windows decided on a asterix to indicate a keystroke

Comment: Still writing :))

Comment: @Neil Meyer: "*asterix*" - In 1998, to honor this common misspelling of "asterisk", I released a login form that replaced each password character with a picture of the comic book character [*Asterix the Gaul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix "by Goscinny and Uderzo"). (Eventually Albert Uderzo indicated that I was not allowed to do this.)

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Now that's a serious cool story - got any documentation put up somewhere?